# Date and Time in URL - not working in FireFox

Tags: datetime, url, firefox

I am using the following datetime format for an URL with DateTime:
...?projectid=10&starttime=2022-12-01t14:10:00z&endtime=2022-12-02t18:10:00z

works fine in every Browser, but FireFox. In FF the time portion is ignored.
Any idea whta might be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you maybe offer a little bit more context? What are you talking about exactly? Is this a particular service you're referring to? At first glance this doesn't seem so be something global related to Firefox.

Comment: I am working with app that was written before me. App's initial screen shows date and time entered into the URL. Every Browser shows date and time correctly except FF.

Comment: BTW, if I remove time portion then dates are shown correctly.

Comment: I would start by looking in the dev tools on the one hand and on the app's side on the other hand and understanding how this is happening with Firefox only. By that I don't mean to say that Firefox necessarily works correctly, but instinctively I don't see what you could change on the browser's side to make this work. So I would try to understand why the application ignores the part in Firefox. This is where I would start digging if I were you.

Comment: I think I see the problem. This code: new Date("2022-12-01t14:10:00z") in Chrome gives the correct date, but in FF it returns Invalid Date.